# Vue: Migrating to vue3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I have a current project in Vue 2.  I saw Vue 3 was released in September ( https://news.vuejs.org/ ) and I'm wondering if there's a guide on how to upgrade.  If there's no migration tool, is there a guide to manually upgrade and what steps to take?

Answer (score 2):

Check out the official documentation: https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/introduction.html

Take in mind that there was some breaking changes, like [Event Bus](https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/blob/master/active-rfcs/0020-events-api-change.md) and [Filters](https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/blob/master/active-rfcs/0015-remove-filters.md) doesn't work any more in Vue3.

According to my understanding (I haven't worked with Vue3 yet) the migration is very easy. So you can still write Vue2 code as usual, even though you have Vue3 installed.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the official guide @wittgenstein mentioned I found [Evan You's talk at VueConf](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WLpLYhnGqPA) helpful. Also, reading through the [Vue RFCs](https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/tree/master/active-rfcs) will help you understand the thinking behind many of the changes, which makes everything much clearer.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Evan You's talk at VueConf Amsterdam](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vp5ANvd88x0&list=PLCxzy-hmQq9HOg0mS0laLkMiTov2zyZ5q&index=1) (september 2020):

- a migration build from V2 to V3 should be available for Q4 2020
- a "2.7 minor release backporting 3.x features and opting-in 3.x compatible behaviours and deprecation warnings", to smoothen the migration to Vue 3, is planned by 2021

*Also, please note that even if Vue 3 is stable, it is not yet the case for the whole environment (for example, Vuex 4 and Vue-next-router are currently in RC), and some sub-projects may not be completely compatible with Vue 3 yet. A 'common switch' (Vue 3 and sub-projects) is also planned by 2021.*

*So, if your project is a large app, it is recommanded to wait for early 2021 to start the migration.*

Answer (score 1):

Vuejs 3 itself is purely additive, but Vuejs 2 third-party libraries and wrapper framework may not be with it just now. E.g. i18n, Vuetify, Nuxtjs.
Nuxtjs 3 will be released in first quarter of 2021, according to October 2020 info.